# Question about probable meaning of 返済 in a sentence

Tags: business-japanese

For the following sentence, what would the likely meaning for "返済" be?

> 製品が完成した場合、製品出荷から返済させていただけますでしょうか

I seems like this word can be used for both repayment of money and return of goods. In this case I can't figure out which of the two meanings it is. The context of this sentence involves making products as well as funding, so it seems that either could apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if 製品出荷から返済, it perhaps means goods because payments of money from shipment is strange but if 製品出荷してから返済, it perhaps means money because it means payments after shipment.

However this sentence is unclear and need more words like 商品の返済、代金(or 負債)の返済.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know this one is hard without context.
For your first interpretation, is " 製品出荷" being used as a noun or a verb? In other words, is it referring to the act of shipping or the shipped product?

Comment: 製品出荷 is noun and 出荷する is verb. 製品を出荷する is more natural. Sorry, I don't know the difference between  the act of shipping and the shipped product. Dictionaries say 出荷 is the thing that companies send  goods from  companies to customers.

Comment: I was curious whether it meant more like 出荷した製品 or 製品出荷した事

Comment: If the company said 出荷した, they sent goods.

Answer (score 0):

Going based off what context I have, the way I made sense of this was to fragment it into two parts, particularly where the comma makes its appearance. This helps separate the clauses.
So, 製品が完成した場合、is referring to a situation in which the goods in question will be finished, and could probably be translated as something like, "When the product is complete..."
製品出荷から返済させていただけますでしょうか This was one where I had to do a literal translation of the text, but I think "Can I perhaps be repaid after the final product ships out?" is probably better than "can receive repayment from final product shipping perhaps?"

I realize translations like this don't exactly do much in the way of helping make sense of the structure, but this at least gives you the right idea of what's being conveyed.